# Getting x,y values from chart click event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, chart.js

I'm using ng2-charts to create a linechart with several clickable points. When I click a point, a click event is triggered - here's the method:

```
public chartClicked(e: any): void {
    console.log('Clicked: ' + e);
}
```

and here's my chart HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <base-chart id="lineChart" class="chart"
                [datasets]="chartData"
                [labels]="chartLabels"
                [colors]="chartColours"
                [legend]="chartLegend"
                [chartType]="chartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, ng2-charts documentation doesn't explain how to actually use the 'e' variable (from what I've seen). I would like to retrieve the x and y values from the clicked point - does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried just looking at the values within 'e' at runtime?

Comment: Is that even valid JS? Looks like another class-based language.

Comment: Chrome dev tools shows 'e' as an [object Object]. Nothing pops up when I try typing in the dot operator - 'e.'

Comment: The chartClicked method was copied from ng2-charts. That function is inside a .ts TypeScript file within an exported class (export class Home{...})

Comment: @Roka545 , that really odd, so it is an empty object? The Chrome Dev tools should let you expand it and see its properties?

Comment: Okay - seems like you can't expand the object when it's added in a print statement like I have in my method. I simply did a console.log(e) and was able to expand and see the object properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Angular2 Chart demos I have discerned the following:

`e` is a container for a) *the chart elements being clicked* and b) *the mouseevent of the click*.

```
e = {
  active: chartData[],
  event: MouseEvent
}
```

So since it appears to be a regular old MouseEvent you should be able to do the following to get the position on the chart:

```
var x:number = e.event.layerX;
var y:number = e.event.layerY;
```

I recommend double checking this and telling me if I am wrong however.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using that code doesn't return the expected chart values - the numbers are way off actually. I did a Ctrl-F in Chrome dev tools and none of the x values or in the returned 'e' object.  Also, I could be wrong, but could it be that e.event.layerX/Y return mouse coordinates, not chart values?

Comment: Oh I thought that is what your question was asking, the position of the click on the graph. Well then look into the array of datapoints in the same event. That should have it's value in the chart.

Comment: Figured this out - easier than I thought. Within the returned object when clicked/hovered ('e' in the code snippet above), their is a '_index' entry - that index corresponds to the index of the point hovered. Here's the object structure where I found it in Chrome developer tools:

*Object {event: MouseEvent, active:Array[1]}
   *active: Array[1]
      *0: i
         * _chart : t
             .....
              __index: 6_